# How to display permanent arrows on the left/right of a carousel when using the Flexslider module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using the [Flexslider](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider) module with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and have a nice carousel running on my Drupal site.

The problem is that the design calls for permanent arrows on the left/right and the module only shows them when you hover over the carousel.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS will get you started:

```
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev,
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {
    left: 0;
}
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {
    right: 0;
}
```

This will also help:

```
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav a:before {
    font-family: serif;
    content: "";
}
```